# python KeyError on parsing a dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, concatenation

How can i join these two text documents?

**document 1:**

```
1000001 10:0.471669 250:0.127552 30:0.218773 64:0.249413
1000002 130:0.0839656 107:0.185613 30:0.446355 110:0.38011
1000003 1:0.0835855 1117:0.0647112 302:0.0851354 46:0.0601825 48:0.098907 516:0.167713
```

**document 2:**

```
1000001 161:0.115664 207:0.136537 294:0.0974809 301:0.199868
1000002
1000003 555:0.0585849 91:0.0164101
```

**result:**

```
1000001 10:0.471669 250:0.127552 30:0.218773 64:0.249413 161:0.115664 207:0.136537 294:0.0974809 301:0.199868
1000002 130:0.0839656 107:0.185613 30:0.446355 110:0.38011
1000003 1:0.0835855 1117:0.0647112 302:0.0851354 46:0.0601825 48:0.098907 516:0.167713 555:0.0585849 91:0.0164101
```

**explanation:**
**document 1** and **document 2** both have the same structure and they have the same number of lines.
 Each line starts with a number (the same number in both documents), and then we have several items in each line which are made up of a number+colon+a decimal number: 
*example* **10:0.471669**
these item combinations are unique, what I want to do is to merge them together: take the items from the second document for each line and put it in the corresponding line of the first document.
*note:*
the initial number at the beginning and the items from one another are separated by a single space.

### update

here is my try:

```
dat1 = {}
with open('doc1') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        dat1[line.split(' ')[0]] = line.strip().split(' ')[1:]

dat2 = {}
with open('doc2') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        key = line.split(' ')[0]
        dat2[key] = line.split(' ')[1:]

for key in dat1.keys():
    print("%s %s %s" % (key, str.join(' ', dat1[key]), str.join(' ', dat2[key])))
```

i get a traceback of KeyError, on the lines of the second document when the line doens't have anything to be added to the first document. It is the case in the second line of the second document in the above example. 
 How can I escape this exception? escape the lines which have only the key and nothing else to add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier way might be to use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

for filename in 'doc1', 'doc2':
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            key, _, value = line.partition(' ')
            data[key.strip()].append(value.strip())

for key in sorted(data):
    print key, ' '.join(data[key])    # Python 2
#    print(key, *data[key])            # Python 3
```

Regarding the printing of the result you could add:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

to the top of your file, and then the Python 3 `print()` function will be available in Python 2, i.e. you can use the Python 3 print above.

---

You asked in a comment how to print to a file (Python 3, or Python 2 after importing `print_function`):

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key in sorted(data):
        print(key, *data[key], file=f)
```

Comment: the output from your code putting parenthesis and at the beginning and end of line, and a comma after the key and brackets for the entire items and a single quote after the bracket! how to remove them and save the output into a file?

Comment: You are using Python 2? Then you can not be printing with the code that I show above, instead you are doing this: `for key in data: print(key, data[key])`. Since you appear to be using Python 2 I have updated the answer to show how to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with newline characters.

At the end of each line in the file there is a newline character which will be included in the last entry of each line. The exception occurs because dat1 will have a key `"1000002"` and dat2 will have a key `"1000002\n"`.

If you have `line = line.strip()` before parsing then the code should work as expected.

```
for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    key = line.split(' ')[0]
    dat2[key] = line.split(' ')[1:]
```

Comment: could you please integrate it into the code? i am lost where to insert it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pop` operation to get the first item of an array, like this:

```
def read_stem(f):
        res = {}
        for line in f.readlines():
                items = line.strip().split()
                res[items.pop(0)] = items
        return res

with open('stem.data') as f:
        dat1 = read_stem(f)

with open('stem.info') as f:
        dat2 = read_stem(f)

with open('myfile','w') as f:
    for key in dat1.keys():
            f.write("%s %s\n" % (key, ' '.join(dat1[key] + dat2[key])))
```

Comment: how to save the output into a file? how to write it to a new file?

Comment: I am trying your solution, but my output file is short of several lines! there are several lines which are missing! however my two source documents have the same number of lines!

Comment: maybe you have some repetitions of the keys in your files. e.g. several lines which start with `1000002 `. If this is the case, my solution will only save the last line with this key and you should use defaultdict instead (see @mhawke answer)

Answer (score 1):

In your code  in 2nd file key for empty row was '1000002\n' not 1000002, that could be the reason, this works.

```
file1_lines= open('doc1', 'r').readlines()
file2_lines = open('doc1', 'r').readlines()
resfile = open('res.txt','w')


dat1 = {}
for line in file1_lines:
    dat1[line.split(' ')[0]] = line.strip().split(' ')[1:]

dat2 = {}
for line in file2_lines:
    dat2[line.strip().split(' ')[0]] = line.strip().split(' ')[1:]

print(dat1)
print(dat2)

for key in dat1.keys():
    print("%s %s %s" % (key, str.join(' ', dat1[key]), str.join(' ', dat2[key])))
    resfile.write("%s %s %s" % (key, str.join(' ', dat1[key]), str.join(' ', dat2[key])))
```

Comment: this is creating a file which contains only one line and everything is dumped into one line. However I am looking to keep the same structure, line by line and just add the elements from the second doc into the first doc? simply by adding to the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
doc1_name = 'doc1'
doc2_name = 'doc2'

def get_key_and_value(key_value_list):
    if len(key_value_list) == 2:
        # list has key and values
        key, value = key_value_list
    elif len(key_value_list) == 1:
        # list only has key
        key, value = key_value_list[0], ''
    else:
        # should not happen!
        key, value = '', ''
    return key,value

def join_dict(key, value, _dict, sep=' '):
    if key in _dict.keys():
        _dict[key] = sep.join((_dict[key], value))
    else:
        _dict[key] = value

result = {}
with open(doc1_name, 'r') as doc1, \
     open(doc2_name, 'r') as doc2:
         doc1_lines = doc1.readlines()
         doc2_lines = doc2.readlines()

for list_of_lines in (doc1_lines, doc2_lines):
    for line in list_of_lines:
        # The .strip('\n') removes the \n at the end
        # and the .split(' ', 1) split only once
        key_value = line.strip('\n').split(' ', 1)
        # split the lines only once to get the keys:
        key, value = get_key_and_value(key_value)
        # this can be ignored if it is known that the keys will be the same
        join_dict(key, value, result)

# order the keys
ordered_keys = result.keys()
ordered_keys.sort()
# and write them to a file
with open('+'.join((doc1_name,doc2_name)),'w') as output:
    for key in ordered_keys:
        output.write(' '.join((key, result[key]))+'\n')
```

### doc1

```
1000001 10:0.471669 250:0.127552 30:0.218773 64:0.249413
1000002 130:0.0839656 107:0.185613 30:0.446355 110:0.38011
1000003 1:0.0835855 1117:0.0647112 302:0.0851354 46:0.0601825 48:0.098907 516:0.167713
```

### doc2

```
1000001 161:0.115664 207:0.136537 294:0.0974809 301:0.199868
1000002
1000003 555:0.0585849 91:0.0164101
```

### doc1+doc2

```
1000001 10:0.471669 250:0.127552 30:0.218773 64:0.249413 161:0.115664 207:0.136537 294:0.0974809 301:0.199868
1000002 130:0.0839656 107:0.185613 30:0.446355 110:0.38011 
1000003 1:0.0835855 1117:0.0647112 302:0.0851354 46:0.0601825 48:0.098907 516:0.167713 555:0.0585849 91:0.0164101
```